# Route Angular to New Controller after Login

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm kind of stuck on how to route my angular app to a new controller after login. I have a simple app, that uses 'loginservice'... after logging in, it then routes to /home which has a different template from the index.html(login page).

I want to use /home as the route that displays the partial views of my flightforms controllers. What is the best way to configure my routes so that after login, /home is the default and the routes are called into that particular templates view. Seems easy but I keep getting the /login page when i click on a link which is suppose to pass the partial view into the default.html template:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', 
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/default.html', 
        controller: 'defaultCtrl'
    });

}]);


flightforms.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
 //sub pages    

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/default.html', 
        controller: 'defaultCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/status', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subpages/home.html', 
        controller: 'statusCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/observer-ao', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subpages/aobsrv.html', 
        controller: 'obsvaoCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/dispatch', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subpages/disp.html', 
        controller: 'dispatchCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/fieldmgr', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subpages/fieldopmgr.html', 
        controller: 'fieldmgrCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/obs-backoffice', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subpages/obsbkoff.html', 
        controller: 'obsbkoffCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/add-user', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subpages/users.html', 
        controller: 'userCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/status'
    });
}]);    

app.run(function($rootScope, $location, loginService) {

    var routespermission=['/home'];  //route that require login
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        if( routespermission.indexOf($location.path()) !=-1)
        {
            var connected=loginService.islogged();
            connected.then(function(msg) {
                if(!msg.data) $location.path('/login');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and my controllers are simple. Here's a sample of what they look like:

```
var flightformsControllers = angular.module('flightformsController', []);

flightforms.controller('fieldmgrCtrl', ['$scope','$http','loginService',
    function($scope,loginService) {
        $scope.txt='You are logged in';
        $scope.logout=function(){
            loginService.logout();
        }
}]);
```

Any ideas on how to get my partials to display in the /home default.html template would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can have 2 routes with the same endpoint, as you do with the /home route in the main app config, and the flightforms config

Comment: Also, why not just redirect to /home in the login controller, after a successful login?  $location.path('/home');

Comment: well, it returns to home just well... just when i click on my navigation items, they do not pull in the partial views in the center of the page like they should.

Comment: plus if the session is not set, it needs to direct users to login... not to the home section of my dashboard.

Comment: What happens when you move all the routing into app.config ?

Comment: Well, redirection back to /login should happen in your routeChangeStart event, if the authentication failed.

Comment: just tried to move all the routes into app.config but now /home hangs after logged in. Before, it loads just fine... @reptilicus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54746/discussion-between-reptilicus-and-mizakita).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Move all the routing into the main app.config, and remove the duplicate route for /home.

2) change this line

```
var flightformsControllers = angular.module('flightformsController', []);
```

to

```
var flightforms = angular.module('flightforms', []);
```

3) change the app definition line to inject the flightforms module:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'flightforms']);
```

That should get ya close.

For one of your comments, its a good idea to have an interecptor which catches any 401 un-authenticated errors from the server. This way, if a user's session expires before a route change, they will still have to login again to start a new session. Something like this in app.config should do it.

```
$provide.factory('logoutOn401', ['$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login')
        return $q.reject();
      } else {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    }
  };
}]);

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('logoutOn401');
```

Comment: outstanding, have fun with ui-router, its the way to go!

Comment: one thing about the $provide.factory - im getting an error back saying $provide not defined... not sure what to reference for this service. @reptilicus

Comment: I think that that *must* be in the app.config block, and just inject $provide in that line.

Comment: app.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide', function($routeProvider, $provide) {

Comment: hmmm... well it killed my login. now you can put any user/pass in and get in. very interesting... is there any documentation on this?

Comment: my app doesnt like $provide.